# styling standard reactjs project

Tags: css, reactjs

I have created a react project by `npx create-react-app my-app`.

There are `App.css` and `index.css`in `src` folder of project. I want to style my `index.js` project but neither of css files are responsible.

What are those files for and how can I globally style my project?

Comment: Please explain the sentence: *neither of css files are responsible*

Comment: Also explain: *can I globally style my project?*. What do you mean by that? You are extremely vague here.

Comment: Those are global CSS files which are loaded via CSS loader (using Webpack). They should be active if you have imported them indirectly via the entry script.

Answer (score 0):

> What are those files for?

When you use CRA (create-ract-app), the app.css & index.css files are there to style the basic react app you get with the CTA template. I know the naming is a bit confusing. Check this issue on CRA github board: [Misleading css files](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2720)

> how can I globally style my project?

To style your app there are lots of ways: CSS Modules, styled-compoment (my fav ourite) ... check out this great article: [5 Ways to style your react app](https://blog.logrocket.com/styling-react-5-ways-style-react-apps/)

Answer (score -1):

> What are those files for

Don't know

> how can I globally style my project?

import a css file in index.js

```
// index.js
import './somecssfile.css'

...
```